# Creating Landscape PDF using WkHtmlToPdf by Mikehaertl

Tags: php, oop, pdf, orientation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using mikehaertl's OOP interface to create pdf using wkhtmltpdf via php. Ref: http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('../WkHtmlToPdf.php');

$pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf(array(
    // Use `wkhtmltopdf-i386` or `wkhtmltopdf-amd64`
    'bin' => 'C:\Users\me\Documents\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
));

// Add a HTML file, a HTML string or a page from a URL
$pdf->addPage('page.html');

if(!$pdf->send())
    throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
```

The above code generates the pdf but it only creates all files in the portrait orientation. How do I change it to landscape orientation? When I searching the web, I found that wkhtlktopdf has an option (-O landscape) to change the orientation but I dont know how to use it with PHP WkHtmlToPdf created by Mikeheart?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by calling `setOptions()` with an array of your desired options, in this case `array('orientation' => 'landscape')` before the `addPage()` call.

```
$pdf->setOptions(array(
    'orientation' => 'landscape'
));
```

As can be seen here: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf#full-example

You can add any other options that can be found under "Global Options" in the [wkhtmltopdf documentation](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html#Global%20Options), to the array you pass in.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I add the orientation like you had suggested, I am getting a fatal error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not create PDF: Could not run command "C:\Users\me\Documents\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE110.tmp.html --orientation "landscape" C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE111.tmp: Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected! --orientation specified in incorrect location Name: wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc2 Synopsis: wkhtmltopdf [GLOBAL OPTION]... [OBJECT]...`

Comment: I think it works if I use setOptions instead of setPageOptions like this: `$pdf->setOptions(array(
    'orientation' => 'landscape'
));`

Comment: You're right. I had tested this with wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 also on Windows 8.1. I've just downloaded wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1 and got the same error. I'll update the answer to use `setOptions` instead and link the newer documentation. Seems that option was moved from the page options to global options. Thanks. :)

Comment: thank you Aleksander. I tested it and the setOptions works fine. You can perhaps edit your answer from setPageOptions() to setOptions(). Also the wkhtmltopdf documentation link you had given is also useful! Cheers and thanks for your support! It was really helpful! :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. I've also linked to the newer wkhtmltopdf documentation which describes which global and which page options are available. For example it might be useful to remove the borders from the generated PDF with: `$pdf->setOptions(array('orientation' => 'landscape', 'margin-top' => '0', 'margin-right' => '0', 'margin-bottom' => '0', 'margin-left' => '0'));`. Thanks for accepting and happy coding!